# Where to ask this?

Tags: discussion

Where to ask a question related to electronic music, but not performance or practice?.

The question is "*Who is the female DJ appearing in the Tomorrowland Aftermovie 2013 min 3:40?*"

Comment: There is currently no place to ask questions about identifying DJ's, but you might be interested the [Music Fans site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans?referrer=z_YAYy-nPlhlGleSE5XxcQ2).

Comment: Thank you so much @AmericanLuke

Comment: Try https://www.quora.com

Answer (score 1):

The [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) site is now in public beta, and questions like this are on topic there.